# aws ecs describe-services - how to get only the latest (newest) message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-ecs

When I use :

`aws ecs describe-services --services xxxx --region eu-west-1 --cluster yyyyy --query 'services[*].events' --output text`

I get the result :

`2021-11-27T18:32:26.536000+05:00        e5e8d86b-51b3-482e-aa2a-d98aa494a541    (service xxxx) has reached a steady state. 2021-11-27T18:32:26.535000+05:00        e0032964-9976-4f72-b332-1b88475cd13d    (service xxxx) (deployment ecs-svc/0725454708180105402) deployment completed. 2021-11-27T18:20:12.797000+05:00        e2cffc87-9ceb-4d7b-9d74-e509d4c416ea    (service xxxx) registered 2 targets in (****) ... ...`

how to get only the latest (newest) message?
like this:

`2021-11-27T18:32:26.536000+05:00        e5e8d86b-51b3-482e-aa2a-d98aa494a541    (service xxxx) has reached a steady state.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`events` is an array and can be indexed:

```
aws ecs describe-services --services xxxx --region eu-west-1 --cluster yyyyy --query 'services[*].events[0]' --output text
```

More info about array slice expressions in JMSPath can be found [here](https://jmespath.org/proposals/array-slices.html).

Comment: Thank you so much - just what we need

Comment: Thank you for your help

can you look at another question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70213086/how-to-set-the-parameter-aws-ecs-update-service-deploymentconfiguration-minimum